# finding the distance between two cities

Tags: prolog

I am working on a problem involving a list of cities and finding which is the closest to a designated one in Prolog. For example if I want to find the closest city to seattle from this data set

```
city(5,3, seattle).
city(22,17,nashville).
city(4,7, portland).
city(21,18, memphis).
city(1,11, sacramento).
```

and I have a predicate/2 defining distance

```
calc(C1,C2,D) :-
   city(V1,H1,C1),
   city(V2,H2,C2),
   D is ((V1-V2)^2+(H1-H2)^2).
```

How could I use findall/3 to calculate the distances to find the closest city?

Answer (score 0):

The formula (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 gives the square of the distance; if the square is lowest, the distance is shortest.

**Edit:** What needs to be accumulated is the pair of nearest city so far, distance^2 as you dig into the list of cities (or work through the facts for cities). Just look at similar examples.

Comment: but i have a problem with the accumulator if you don't mind explaining that part as well?